# Play a sound when button pressed application wide

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF application that should be used on a touch screen. I have been asked to play a sound when a button is pressed on the screen, for the whole application.
My idea was to create a style to do this, include the resource dictionnary in my app.It works quite well.
However, this style is in a separate DLL and I would like my main application to change the path of the sound file (BoutonClickSound Url below). But I could not find a way to do it.
I have tried several ugly things like :

```
    System.Windows.Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries[0]["BoutonClickSound"] = new Uri(m_MainVM.ButClickSoundPath);
System.Windows.Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries[0].MergedDictionaries[0]["BoutonClickSound"] = new Uri(m_MainVM.ButClickSoundPath);
```

But none of them seems to work...

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:primitives="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;assembly=PresentationFramework"
                xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System">

<sys:Uri x:Key="BoutonClickSound">c:\buttonclick.wav</sys:Uri>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}"  x:Key="SoundButton">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="PreviewMouseDown">
            <SoundPlayerAction x:Name="SoundPlayer" Source="{DynamicResource BoutonClickSound}" />
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type primitives:Selector}"  x:Key="SoundSelectionChange">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="SelectionChanged">
            <SoundPlayerAction x:Name="SoundPlayer" Source="{DynamicResource BoutonClickSound}" />
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Any idea how to do this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare a local resource with the same key.

If you want it globally in your application, you can add it to a MergedDictionary **after** you include the MergedDictionary from your library.

Add another entry like this:

```
<sys:Uri x:Key="BoutonClickSound">c:\differentfile.wav</sys:Uri>
```

And it should cause your style to use that file instead.

**Edit:**

To set the resource in the code-behind, first you must add it to the local resource dictionary:

```
Resources.Add("BoutonClickSound", new Uri("your uri here"));
```

After you add it, if you want to later change it, you can't re-add it, you have to modify it:

```
Resources["BoutonClickSound"] = new Uri("your uri here");
```

Comment: Moozhe, thank you for you reply. And what if I want to set the BoutonClickSound URI by code behind ?

Comment: Is it possible to do it in the App.xaml (and .cs) ? I added the ResourceDictionary in App.xaml and the local key after. That works OK. But when I try to change the App.cs Application Startup event with `Resources["BoutonClickSound"] = new Uri(filepath);` , it doesn't seem to update the soundfile... Actually the name of the wav file to play will come from a configuration file, so will not be known at compile time.

Comment: It is my understanding you are originally defining that ResourceKey in a ResourceDictionary, and you are including it in your App.xaml as a MergedDictionary.  In this case, if you want to override it at the application level you must add the resource to a later dictionary.  For example, if the ResourceDictionary you are linking to from another project is Resources.MergedDictionary[0], you must add an entry to Resources.MergedDictionary[1] or later to override it.

Comment: Yes, when overriding the ResourceKey in the xaml, it works. But I would like to overide it by code (the file path will come from a config file), but it doesn't seem to work. It still plays the filename overriden in the xaml file.

Comment: I just tested it with code and it worked for me.  I include a ResourceDictionary in my App.xaml file, then override the same key in the Application.OnStartup override in the code-behind.  I simply set it with the syntax "Resources["resourceKey"] = new Uri("...");"  The Resources dictionary in the App.xaml will override any merged dictionaries if there is a duplicate key.